# Python / Tkinter - Label out of Vertical Alignment

Tags: python, tkinter

could you help with the following problem?

Using Python's Tkinter I have coded a small app with a GUI.

Yet, one label of the GUI is moved upwards and not in vertical alignment
with the other element (a Scale) within the same row. See pic attached.

This problem occurs only once and not with other elements that are perfectly
aligned side by side within their respective rows.

I used the grid geometry manager.

**How could I bring the label into vertical alignment with scale in the same row?**
Are there maybe some options for the grid manager to be specified?
I red the grid doc but I am not sure what to do.

The code for the GUI part (shorted to focus on the essential, repetitive elements deleted):

```
#-----Scale: ---------------------------------------------
S = Scale(master, from_=1, to=7, orient=HORIZONTAL)
S.set(2)
S.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

#-----Labels: -----------------------------------------------
LS = Label(master, text="# of mirs:")
LS.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1)

L1 = Label(master, text="mir 1:")
L1.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1)

L2 = Label(master, text="mir 2:")
L2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=1)

#-----Entry Fields: -----------------------------------------------
SPACER1 = Label(master, text="")
SPACER1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4)

E1 = Entry(master)
E1.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)

E2 = Entry(master)
E2.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)

#-----Buttons: ----------------------------------------------
SPACER2 = Label(master, text="")
SPACER2.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=4)

QUIT = Button(master, text="QUIT", command=master.destroy)
QUIT.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify `sticky='S'` (south = bottom) and specify `pady` (or `ipady`).

```
LS.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='S', ipady=4)
```

[image: result screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your lightning fast answer! It worked for me! -Tom